# cross-origin getSVGDocument() not allowed even cors is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, svg, cross-domain

I am getting an error while trying to access an svg file's content if the svg file is served from another server, even though that server sends `access-control-allow-origin:*` header

This is the html code of the svg object:

```
<object id="idSvg" data="http://cdnserver.com/file.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

This is the code where I get the error:

```
jQuery('#idSvg')[0].addEventListener('load', function() {

    var doc = this.getSVGDocument(); // <-- error comes here
```

This is the error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'getSVGDocument' on
>   'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.com"
>   from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>
> at HTMLObjectElement. (http://example.com)

This is the header for the svg file served by the cdnserver.com

```
access-control-allow-origin:*
cache-control:max-age=604800
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:image/svg+xml
date:Sat, 25 Mar 2017 05:58:30 GMT
expires:Sat, 01 Apr 2017 05:58:30 GMT
last-modified:Sun, 22 Jan 2017 08:53:52 GMT
server:keycdn-engine
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
x-cache:MISS
x-edge-location:defr
```

Why would I get the error when the cdn server is serving the file with cors headers?

**EDIT:**

example.com is the server where I am working.

cdnserver.com is the server where the file is served from.